# Hive on Spark - java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SPARK_RPC_SERVER_ADDRESS

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

My Apps versions are below. I am unable to run a SELECT using beeline command line. Are these versions compatible?.

​Hadoop - 2.7.3 
Hive  -  2.3.0 
Spark  - 2.0.2

```
java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: SPARK_RPC_SERVER_ADDRESS
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.rpc.RpcConfiguration.<clinit>(RpcConfiguration.java:47)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.<init>(RemoteDriver.java:134)
    at org.apache.hive.spark.client.RemoteDriver.main(RemoteDriver.java:516)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$$anon$2.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:627)
```

Comment: did u resolve? i have same error

Comment: @tooptoop4 , Better to use HDP packages as they are stable & compatible. I resolved it but i dont remember the solution.

Comment: Can anyone please direct me towards the changes required on the hive and spark libraries or configurations?